# React: Cannot set property of DEBUG #Object which only has a getter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, variables, module

So I have 3 files:

**config.js**

```
export var DEBUG = false;
```

**database.js**

```
const Config = require('./config');

const Database = {
    setConfig: {
        debug() {
            Config.DEBUG = true;
        }
    }
};
```

**index.js**

```
const Database = require('./database').Database;

Database.setConfig.debug();
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "what's wrong"? Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: Lefteris008 read the title

Comment: You should refactor your question, embed the error in its description and provide a full stack trace.